Extremely intermittent leak through ceiling on first floor of two story house
Looking for next steps on identifying the source of a leak in our home. The ceiling in one of our downstairs rooms has leaked on three occasions, but has never been more than a cup of water at most, and there are long gaps of time between the leaks. Any advice on some next steps I could take would be greatly appreciated.
Details:

First we saw water dripping from a ceiling joist and called a plumber to look; he cut this hole on the left and found no plumbing or obvious source of the leak in the area. The joist that was dripping is visible on the left. About a month later, a small amount of water dripped from the spot on the right identified by the green sticky note, which manifested a crack in the paint in that spot.


About a month after that leak, we had another very small amount of water dripping from both the newly opened leak search hole (bottom right corner of the cut in this picture) and from the area with the cracked paint.
It hasn't leaked since then, about a month and a half.
This room is below the master bathroom with a water closet, two sinks, a jetted tub and a shower. All of these fixtures get regular to daily use and the dripping does not seem to be correlated to any kind of usage.
On a hunch from the plumber, had an inspector look at the roof and attic for damage that could let water in and he found none. This was a long shot though as the leaks haven't correlated with rainy days, and we've had many days with very strong rain and no visible leaking.
The leaking ceiling crack and the leak search hole are parallel along the same joist. My impression from poking around during the simultaneous leak is that the source is either near the crack or upstream in that direction, and then flowing along the joist to come out via the leak search hole.
The jetted tub is a suspect - we had the overflow plumbing replaced late last year after it leaked through the ceiling on the other side of the room. The hole cut for that repair is still open since we've been having this other leak, so I'm reasonably sure it's not an issue with the plumbing that was replaced, but the rest of the tub plumbing is reasonably old and likely original. I'd like to have this inspected but I'm not sure if I need a specialist of some kind for that. (overflow repair hole is on the left; right hole was cut to inspect the wax seal on the toilet for leaks which also turned up nothing):


Since it's been over a month since the last leak, I'm hesitant to bring a plumber out to search again just to pay to have them cut a hole in that spot and find dry insulation and no plumbing or leak source again. My other option seems to be just waiting for the leak to happen again and trying to get someone in ASAP to source it, which seems stressful and may cause more hidden damage in the meantime.
I do have some tools I can use to dig into it myself (moisture meter, FLIR camera) but it seems like these might only have value while the leak is actively happening, at which point I'd just call someone to cut it open and try to fix it.
Any and all advice is appreciated - if the best course of action is just some more exploratory cutting as soon as possible then I'll do that first, but hoping to avoid playing whack-a-mole with repeated cuts.
EDIT: Adding some photos of the flooring above the area of the leak; some type of tile, not laminate. The leak crack is approximately below the middle of this photo:

Some potential candidates I found:
Cracked tiles near the bathroom threshold

Some gaps where the bathtub joins to the wall:

The tub also has this access panel that doesn't have any seal around the outside and has some gaps at the bottom; it seems reasonable some water could have collected on the lip of the tub, running behind the panel and through the gap into the floor:



It's water, not rocket science. :) Investigate from most accessible area to least accessible. There's really no secret to share.

Plumbing leaks should almost be constant.  Roof leaks should happen during or soon after rain.  Your leaks sound almost like water spilling on the floor and seeping though.  Having a bathroom above with tubs helps this idea.  Edit your question with the type of flooring and pictures.

Any kids?  That might be a source.

@crip659 Thank you! I added some photos of the bathroom floor above the leak and some candidate gaps/damage that look like they could be letting water through. I can probably get some treatment and fill in most of these myself just to be sure, but is there any way to test which one might be the cause? (Short of pouring water into it and seeing what happens?)

Also - no kids, but the tub is fairly awkward to get into and out of and the floor in there definitely gets wet through normal usage. There are usually some thick bath mats I removed to inspect the floor; they may contribute to how intermittent the leak has been.

The kids were there to blame hopefully.  Now you only have yourself to blame.  Cracked tiles and missing/crack grout are good places for leaking.  You want a wet(bathroom) floor to be sealed from wall to wall.  Crack tiles might mean a weak/not solid enough sub floor, or you dropped a heavy object on it.

The paths water takes through a house can be unintuitive; where it becomes visible may be quite different from where it starts. If the times when you see it don't correspond to when you were using that tub l, it may be coming from outside...

I would start with sealing up any obvious cracks.  [Replace] Caulk around the tub, any corners in tiled locations—if the "where the bathtub joins to the wall" pic is grout, that's wrong and it should be caulked instead.  Once you're fairly certain it's not surficial water making its way below, you can move on to investigating plumbing.
